# how to make the exe work on another PC if it uses other non-standard libraries?

Tags: c++, json

Hi I'm a newbie to programming, I made a c++ program in Visual Studio that uses a json library and reads a .json file, it works fine when I run it from Visual Studio so from the Project folder where VS stores it, but what if I wanted to send the program to another PC so that another person can just run the .exe and it would work on their PC as well?

How could I make it so that on their PC the program knows how to handle json when its not a standard library and also read the correct json file?

I have no experience in this so there's nothing I could think of yet

Comment: Normally, to run your app in a different place, you copy not ony the `.exe` file, but also all not-standard libs `.dll`  your app needs (look at your linker options & files). People like to put all of it in the same dir.

Comment: NSIS and WIX are good choices for an installer.

Comment: Apart from the library you most likely also need to distribute your compilers runtime. See for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 1):

Either use a static version of the json library so that the json code is linked in as an intrinsic part of your program (you may in fact already be doing this), or create an installer that bundles the json DLL file with your program and installs them both as a unit on the target system.

I know there are free install-makers available but I've little experience with them so can't really make a recommendation.